# How Show New Url Of MappedUrl At Page Start? (Url-Mapping)

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting, url-mapping

i wrote the code belwo for url-mapping :

```
<urlMappings enabled="true">
  <add url="~/My Fantastic Page" mappedUrl="~/Default.aspx" />
</urlMappings>
```

my purpose is when somebody types my domain in his/her address bar, see

> (http://www.domain.com/My Fantastic Page)

instead of

> (http://www.domain.com/Default.aspx)

how can i show new url of mapped url at page start?
should i use url-mapping for this purpose or url-routing?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, it's better to use ASP.NET Url Routing instead of an obsoleted technique like Url mapping (Of course, in ASP.NET 4.0), check it out:

[URL Routing with ASP.NET 4 Web](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/13/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx) forms From scottgu

Also, for .NET Framework 3.5 SP1:

[Routing with ASP.NET Web Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd347546.aspx) from Scott Allen

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer. my issue is how show My Fantastic Page -> instead of Default.aspx after page load? which code should i use? i wrote scottgu codes in global.asax but nothing happens!  also in those samples we only read route valuse. but how can i force that page to change it's url at start?

Comment: If you asked me, I prefer a nameless startup page. However you can use IIS Redirect feature http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpRedirect or Phil Haack's RouteMagic https://github.com/haacked/routemagic

Answer (score 0):

You must specify like this:

```
<urlMappings enabled="true">
  <add url="~/My Fantastic Page.aspx" mappedUrl="~/Default.aspx" />
</urlMappings>
```

Comment: hi, by this change i have this error:  The resource cannot be found